# neo4j about how to join two cypher with where

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can run this cypher sucessfully :

```
match (n1:person)-[]-(a:track) 
with  n1,collect(a.num_of_related) as adc where all( t1 in adc where t1=1)
match (n:person)-[]-(b:track)
where  n1.name=n.name return n1,b
union all
match (n1:person)-[]-(b:track) where b.num_of_related>1 return n1,b
```

but when I change the order of the two queries,like :

```
match (n:person)-[]-(b:track)
match (n1:person)-[]-(a:track) 
with  n1,collect(a.num_of_related) as adc where all( t1 in adc where t1=1)
where  n1.name=n.name return n1,b
union all
match (n1:person)-[]-(b:track) where b.num_of_related>1 return n1,b
```

It will give out an error , like :

```
Invalid input 'h': expected 'i/I' (line 3, column 2 (offset: 139))
"where  n1.name=n.name return n1,b"
^
```

It looks like there can not be another where after the second cypher . But if I really need a where to join the two cypher after the second match, how can I write the right cypher ?

tks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you cut/paste your query, you missed to cut it properly. When you wrote below:

```
where  n1.name=n.name
```

the variable n is not available anymore because the previous "With" statement does not include n.

Comment: the "with" statement belongs to the second match , like :

```cypher

---match (n:person)-[]-(b:track)  ---part 1
---match (n1:person)-[]-(a:track) 
with  n1,collect(a.num_of_related) as adc where all( t1 in adc where t1=1)----part 2
---where  n1.name=n.name return n1,b  ---part 3
---union all
match (n1:person)-[]-(b:track) where b.num_of_related>1 return n1,b  ---part 4
```

Comment: You need to add the variable n to your WITH statement because it will be used in the  WHERE n1.name=n.name.

Comment: If I add "n" to the WITH statement, the result of COLLECT will be changed. And if I add the "n" to WITH statement, the error is :

```cypher
Invalid input 'h': expected 'i/I' (line 3, column 2 (offset: 143))
"where  n1.name=n.name return n1,b"
  ^
```

Comment: I only explains what the error is. I have no idea of your data, model and what you want to do. I cannot help you without knowing them.